# Collection insert multiple - ensure uniqueness

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The main goal is: **Insert multiple documents at a time but ensure only unique ones are stored in the collection** Explanation below

I'm inserting many documents into a mongodb collection at once like so:

```
db.users.insert([{name: 'Joe'}{'name': 'Bob'}]);
```

Some of the values going into the insert may be duplicate and i would like MongoDB to ignore these. This is to ensure uniqueness within the collection.

```
db.users.insert([{name: 'Joe'}{'name': 'Jack'}]);
```

Using an index the whole `.insert()` operation will fail if the whole insert is not unique instead of just the non unique items being ignored.

```
db.users.createIndex({ 'name': 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Log from mongoDB:

```
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: name_1 dup key: { : \"Joe\" }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57f924ee7d864acfefaca700"),
                "name" : "joe"
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What you really want ? will you please elaborate it more

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad I thought the question was pretty clear... I want to insert multiple documents at a time but ensure only unique ones are stored in the collection. Adding this to the question post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people looking for an answer to this. I eventually use a bulk `update.upsert()` operation. This meant that I could keep my capped collection, make sure it was ordered and for the whole operation to still be in bulk.

This removed the need for the unique index, as `upsert` always updates/inserts the data ensuring we don't have duplicates.
The find operation should include the unique keys.

```
const bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({name: 'Joe'}).upsert().updateOne({name: 'Joe'});
bulk.find({name: 'Bob'}).upsert().updateOne({name: 'Bob'});
bulk.find({name: 'Jack'}).upsert().updateOne({name: 'Jack'});
bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the comment. Maybe you're looking fro something like this. [**UnorderedBulkOp**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/)

The magic cames from that Unordered Bulk Operations occur in parallel. if one ( or some) of them fai, MongoDB continue with the rest and shouts the errors at the end.

Comment: the specific collection I have is a capped collection so actually it matters for the operation to be ordered :( looking at the docs though it seems I could just use ordered bulk operation instead?

Comment: Actually that's not going to work. I see now why you recommended Unordered bulk operations here... `If an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations, MongoDB will return without processing any remaining write operations in the list.` Maybe the only way is to insert one by one then

Answer (score 0):

For inserting multiple documents with some unique key, you may create an index, where you can declare that key to be unique.
Like in your case, you can create index using this command,

*db.users.createIndex({"name":1},{unique:true})*

Comment: That line is literally in the post... I was already doing that